# How add a cookie to specific domain using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to specify the domain in which the cookie is to be set.

I followed this way

selenium.open(example.com);
selenium.createCookie(arg1, arg2);

Is there any way by which i can set the cookie in .example.com domain?

Note : If i open example.com it will be redirected to www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selenium.open(...);
selenium.createCookie("name=value", "domain=.example.com");
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/tags/selenium-2.0-rc-2/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#createCookie%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29